# How to start using $q?

Tags: angularjs, q

I've tried to inject $q in my controller like this:

```
app.controller('NodeCtrl', ['Tree', function(Tree, $scope, $element, $q) {
```

But, `$q` is not defined, how can I start using it? I am using Angular 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject it as well as add it to your argument list:

```
app.controller('NodeCtrl', ['Tree', '$scope', '$element', '$q', 
               function(Tree, $scope, $element, $q) {
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, however, I wonder why all those down votes for the question! I feel as the community is getting a little bit paranoid

Comment: It's unfortunate some people down vote without commenting how to improve the question. It might be the wording in the title; something like "How do I inject '$q' into my controller?" might be a bit more specific and also encourage people to read on.

Comment: Thanks seanhodges, I will try to be more thoughtful when writing the next question